# How to combine the result of 2 svm classifiers optimaly?

Tags: java, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I am completely new to SVM
I have trained 2 SVM classifiers with same data set and different features extracted from it. I am using opencv ml package in java. and i get the predict result  with

```
  featureResults[i][j] = features[i][j].predict(newOutput, true);
```

now i need to combine the results. How can i do that optimally with less error?

Comment: should be covered by the topic `sensor fusion`. Maybe bayesian networks might help you. In the literature example you can use conditional probabilities to improve the decision whether the alarm went on because of a burglary or an earthquake http://vlm1.uta.edu/~athitsos/courses/cse4308_fall2011/assignments/programming5/burglary.gif

Comment: my data is images and that right now i am taking just the average and mapping it to [0,1] , and the results are bad.

Comment: Your data is the classifier results. If you know each classifier's probabilities of being right you might combine them with bayes, maybe.

Comment: Since this is a question about statistical methodology rather than programming, I think it's more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If i understood your problem right, you don't need to train two svm classifiers. You can use your dataset twice to train 1 classifier with different features. That would be the easy way